# Check if a date is greater than the first week end date of a month

Tags: javascript

This is how I am checking if a date is greater than the end-date of the first week.

Is there a better approach for this?

I also need to check the time along with the date.

```
function getTodayDate() {
  var today = new Date();
  var dd = today.getDate();
  var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

  if (dd < 10) {
    dd = '0' + dd
  }

  if (mm < 10) {
    mm = '0' + mm
  }

  today = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;

  return today;
}

function getFirstWeekDate() {
  var today = new Date();
  var dd = "7";
  var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

  if (dd < 10) {
    dd = '0' + dd
  }

  if (mm < 10) {
    mm = '0' + mm
  }

  return dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;
}

var startDate = getTodayDate();
var endDate = getFirstWeekDate();

var regExp = /(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{2,4})/;

if (parseInt(endDate.replace(regExp, "$3$2$1")) < parseInt(startDate.replace(regExp, "$3$2$1"))) 
{

}
```

Comment: look at [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: There *is* a Date object in javascript.  When you convert to string, it should be for showing the user.  If then, you're converting it to something you can compare then you're probably doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with your approach.

First, you're not actually checking the date of the weekend. You're just comparing it against the seventh day, so you're really checking if the date is one of the first six days of the month, and there are better ways to check that (such as calling `getDate()`).

Second, you are trying to treat the date as a number, but putting the most significant digits (the year) towards the end, which is backwards from how they should sort things. This works ok for your specific practice, since the month and year will always be the same in this instance, but if you're actually comparing any two dates it is wrong. If you're including time, it is especially wrong. In this case, you have two better solutions

1. Turn your dates into (tz consistent or tz free) ISO 8601 dates which will sort correctly. You can use the `toISOString()` method of a `Date` to do so.
2. Use a library such as [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) to do the date manipulation and comparison.

For example, if you had a Date object in `now`, you could create a Moment object representing this with

```
var nowMoment = moment(now);
```

which you could then use for various manipulations and comparisons. For example, if you wanted the end of the week for the month represented by nowMoment, you could do the following to get the start of the month and then the end of the first week

```
var weekEnd = moment(now).startOf('month').endOf('week');
```

You can then compare these. So if you wanted to know if the `now` variable is before the end of the first week, you can use something like

```
var isFirstWeek = nowMoment.isBefore( weekEnd );
```